# Second While loop returns one instance

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, do-while

The code below is just a snippet of my entire code, the issue I have is that the first while loop returns all the instances, but the second while loop returns only one instance. I've tried putting them in different functions, but that did not help, can someone help?

```js
    function refreshCurveData() {
    selectedDate = document.querySelectorAll(".buyclass .column-date.sorting_1")[1].textContent;
    buyPriceTable = document.querySelectorAll(".buyclass td.column-price");
    buyVolTable = document.querySelectorAll(".buyclass td.column-volume");

    sellPriceTable = document.querySelectorAll(".sellclass td.column-price");
    sellVolTable = document.querySelectorAll(".sellclass td.column-volume");

    let i = 0;
    do {
        var buyPriceData1 = buyPriceTable[i].textContent;
        var buyVolData1 = buyVolTable[i].textContent;

        buyPriceData[i] = {
            x: parseFloat(buyPriceData1.replace(/\,/g, '')),
            y: parseFloat(buyVolData1.replace(/\,/g, ''))
        };
        i++;
    }        
    while (document.querySelectorAll(".buyclass .column-date.sorting_1")[i].textContent === selectedDate);

    let j = 0;
    do {    
        var sellPriceData1 = sellPriceTable[j].textContent;
        var sellVolData1 = sellVolTable[j].textContent;

        sellPriceData[j] = {
            x: parseFloat(sellPriceData1.replace(/\,/g, '')),
            y: parseFloat(sellVolData1.replace(/\,/g, ''))
        };

        j++;
    }
    while (document.querySelectorAll(".sellclass .column-date.sorting_1")[j].textContent === selectedDate);
}

setInterval(() => {
    refreshCurveData();
    scatterChart.update();

}, 2500);
```

Comment: The snippet just gives errors without the underlying data. Are you sure there is more than one instance in the sellPrice table?

Comment: yes there is, even when I run a document.querySelectorAll on the table via console.log, I get all the data.

Comment: I think we need to see some of the underlying data. Can you post what you see in console.log?

Comment: why don't you use `document.querySelectorAll('.selector').forEach(element => { ... })` Then you will loop through all elements and don't need to check yourself?